# Can a ClearCase VOB Server be setup on a multihomed system?

Tags: clearcase, firewall

Any reason why I can't configure  ClearCase VOB server to be multihomed with one NIC on my lab network and the other the developers' network?

A bunch of lab systems need access to our ClearCase VOB server but it's on a different network with a firewall in between. I'd like to avoid the nightmare of firewall configuration by creating a dualhomed system.

If this something which ClearCase supports, has problems with, or is oblivious to?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a multihomed host (In the Internet Protocol (IP), a host that is connected to more than one network) is supported or not for ClearCase.

I know:

- this kind of configuration isn't mentioned in the [system requirements for ClearCase.](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/clearcase/sysreq/)
- I have multihoming (as in "multiple hostnames on the same network over the same communications line") enabled on Linux and Solaris10 (but with zones, meaning each zone represent an independent host in itself).
  If you mention as server name the name associated with a given IP, it works without any particular issue.